# CLI EOL [End of Line] converter

Tags: shell, unix, centos, command-line-interface, eol

I've been looking for commands or tools that I can use in the shell to convert a given file from `DOS` to `Unix` in terms of newlines and carriage returns. I have found [one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eol-converter-cli) but this is only available through `npm`. I currently do this manually through Notepad++ but this is quite tedious and was wondering if there is a tool I could use for `CentOS` or `Linux` to achieve this via shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`dos2unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix). Should be available from your package manager if it's not already installed (`sudo yum install dos2unix`).

Comment: Sounds good. Just a note that this is a duplicate of several questions on the [unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19402/converting-dos-text-files-to-unix)